# Unable to search for more than 20 chars in azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

We are currently running into an issue when expanding our current azure search features.
When we have the following string indexed in azure search:

AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE02000UHKPT

And we search for that complete string, we are not able to find it.
However, when we only use 20 chars, we are able to find it.
So the with the string below, we are able to find it

AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE

However, when adding just 1 more char it disappears again. And this is not only within our implementation. This is also in azure itself when entering this within the query string

The field is set up as

- Retrievable
- Filterable
- Searchable

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your scenario now, and it works fine. I cannot reproduce the problem you have. You don't specify which analyzer you use, so I'm going to assume you use the standard analyzer.

Here is how I tested.

1. I create a new index with two fields Id and Ordcode.
2. I upload two records via Postman

   ```
   "value": [
   {
       "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
       "Id": "1",
       "Ordcode" : "AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE02000UHKPT"
   },
   {
       "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
       "Id": "2",
       "Ordcode": "ABC123"
   }]
   ```
3. I search for your the string AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE02000UHKPT using searchMode=all, queryType=full. The response is as expected.

   ```
   {
   "@odata.context": "https://<search-service>.search.windows.net/indexes('dg-test-65143696')/$metadata#docs(*)",
   "@odata.count": 1,
   "value": [
       {
           "@search.score": 0.2876821,
           "Id": "1",
           "Ordcode": "AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE02000UHKPT"
       }
   ]
   ```

   }
4. I also tried to reproduce via the Search Explorer in the Azure Portal, even with simple mode and any (the default).

   search=AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE02000UHKPT&$count=true&$select=Id,Ordcode

There is a limit on the tokens produced (depending on the analyzer you use), but it's not 20 unless you have defined a shorter max token length.

Comment: We have this both through the search explorer as well as through our code. When using the search explorer we are using API Version 2020-06-30. Using querytype full does not fix the issue in there, havent tried it in our code yet however. Searchmode is set to Any or our end, however using all also does not fix the issue. Also no analyzer is set in the field.

Comment: As an addition, i have created a new search index and only added the 1 value. When i search for it in the search explorer with the full name it indeed finds it now. However, when trying to partially search for it, it does not work.

Comment: Checked out the index definition we currently have, which is not really easy to find btw, and apparently we have a EdgeNGramTokenizer with minGram 1 and maxGram 20. Creating a new index with maxGram 50 solves the issue. However we are not able to change these, so a new index it is then!

Comment: You'll find the index definition in the Azure Search Portal by clicking on your index and then the tab called Index Definition (JSON). By the way, your example where you search for a partial code like AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE is expected to produce no hits in your case. You can specify a wildcard search if that's what you mean by adding a * to the end of the query like this: AEDE190EACWWG4VGLDE*.